# About vino setting using command line

Tags: c, linux, command

1. default setting
   [image: default setting]
2. setting changed.
   [image: setting changed]

How can I set this in command line?

I'm going to write a  c program using system() call.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some documentation on archlinux: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vino

From a command line, you would have to type:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino vnc-password $(echo -n 'mypasswd'|base64)
```

So, the equivalent C source should be:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    char command[256];
    sprintf(command, "gsettings set org.gnome.Vino vnc-password $(echo -n '%s'|base64)", argv[1]);

    system(command);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this code lakes at least:

- test that the program is called with one parameter
- use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf` (to prevent writing to much data in `command`)